# Create new column in Pandas with value that corresponds to a unique pair of records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that includes two columns of integers. I'm trying to identify the unique pairs of records by creating a new column that is an unique identifier for that record pair. Below is an example of my data.

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

The result I'm looking for would look like the below.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |

The goal would be to map a value to each column pair.
(1,1) = 1,
(1,2) = 2,
(1,3) = 3 and so forth. I have been trying to use groupby and apply but can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df['Column 3'] = (df.groupby(['Column 1', 'Column 2']).cumcount() == 0).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
0         1         2         1
1         1         2         1
2         1         3         2
3         1         4         3
```

Another way:

```
df['Column 3'] = df.apply(tuple, axis=1).factorize()[0] + 1
```

A third way:

```
df['Column 3'] = (~df.duplicated(['Column 1', 'Column 2'])).cumsum()
```

Thank you @shubhamsharan, fourth way:

```
df['Column 3'] = df.groupby(['Column 1', 'Column 2']).ngroup().add(1)
```

Comment: ...and today I learned about [factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)! Neat trick!

Comment: A fourth way `df.groupby(['Column 1', 'Column 2']).ngroup().add(1)` ;-)